# Skip Master Chooser

Tags: ros, master, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing an android app with rosjava, and I am setting the Master URI programatically. Therefore, the Master Chooser screen does nothing for me. Is there a way I can skip it totally?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55874/skip-master-chooser/) by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to Kazuto for the lead, but there are a few issues with his answer. I was able to solve them with the included code. First, I changed startMasterChooser in RosActivity.java to public, and then pasted this code into my activity:

```
@Override
  public void startMasterChooser() {
    
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String masterURI = prefs.getString("masterURI", "http://192.168.1.113:11311");
    
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("ROS_MASTER_URI", masterURI);
    onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, data);
    
  }
```

Alternatively, you can just hardcode the masterURI...I chose to have it as a preference. Hopefully changing the RosActivity code doesn't have any effect on future work.

---

Originally posted by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) with karma: 93 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) on 2013-02-25**:
I think this is better solution because it can work well without adding a new global variable.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Master Chooser is called in the startMasterChooser() method, and this method is public.
So you can override it in your original activity class.

For example:

```
@Override
public void startMasterChooser() {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(ROS_MASTER_URI);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
        }

        nodeMainExecutorService.setMasterUri(uri);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                CustomActivity.this.init(nodeMainExecutorService);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
}
```

ROS_MASTER_URI is your fixed URI.

CustomActivity is your original activity class.

---

Originally posted by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) with karma: 116 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on 2013-02-25**:
Few issues. First, startMasterChooser is private. You have to change that in the gingerbread package. Second, nodeMainExecutor cannot be accessed this way. More changes would have to be made the RosActivity file. Instead, you can do what I did...see my solution.

**Comment by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) on 2013-02-25**:
Oh, you are right, I forget changing my RosActivity class and making nodeMainExecutorService global before, I'm sorry! Actually, my program works well with above codes.